# Ember Data Beta 2 - Serializer/Deserializer for FixtureAdapter

Tags: javascript, serialization, ember.js, ember-data

As I understand it, `DS.FixtureAdapter` doesn't use a serializer by default. Is this correct?

I'm mainly trying to get custom transforms working with the fixture adapter. I see `DS.JSONSerializer` calls the deserialize method of the transform [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L14), but over [here in the fixture adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L28) the `serializer` property is set to `null`. It also looks like all the fixture adapter's find methods return the fixtures [directly](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L162).

In comparison, `DS.RESTAdapter` has its `ajax` method, which [claims](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L391) to call the proper flavor of `extract` from the serializer. However, I don't see where this is done. Where in source does this occur?

Is there a property or something that I can override to hook the fixture adapter up with a serializer? (I tried `serializer: DS.JSONSerializer` in my fixture adapter, but this just seems to block all data from being loaded.) Or am I looking at modifying the source being the only solution? If so, knowing where/how the REST adapter invokes `extractSingle`/`extractArray` would be amazing.

I appreciate any help I can get. I'm at a bit of a dead end with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extractSingle`/`extractArray` are called within the `extract` method of `JSONSerializer`.

```
var specificExtract = "extract" + requestType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + requestType.substr(1);
return this[specificExtract](store, type, payload, id, requestType);
```

Some fancy "meta programming" makes them very hard to find since they don't show up in a grep.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L113-L114

[UPDATE] :  The main `extract` method is called from within the `store`.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1399

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1414

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1427

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1441

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1456

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1473

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually found `extractSingle`/`extractArray` from reading the `extract` method originally. I'm currently lost as to where `RESTAdapter` calls `extract`. All I can find is [this success callback](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/ddaa5fa3b77c547315777a3e8609a9f30585db80/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L434) in the `ajax` method, but how this links into `JSONSerializer`'s `extract` method is what I'm missing.

Comment: I just added an [UPDATE] pointing to the places where `extract` is called.

Comment: Okay, so `extract` gets called from the store... It looks like adding `serializer: DS.JSONSerializer.create()` to my fixture adapter gets me headed in the right direction. (It wasn't working before because I tried providing a class or a string. Apparently Ember doesn't do the "heavy lifting" here, but that's fine.) Now Ember is attempting to lookup transforms for the payload (which is good), but when the serializer [attempts the lookup](http://goo.gl/6VF8iw) it can't find the container (which is bad). `this.container` comes up undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is probably a dependency injection thing.  Instead of `create`ing a serializer, I think maybe you should `extend` one as your `ApplicationSerializer`.  `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({});`

Comment: That fixed the serializer issue. Thanks so much! However, I had to override JSONSerializer's `extractArray` method because it was exactly the same as the `extractSingle` method. It passed the payload array directly to `normalize` and thus `applyTransform`, both of which expect to receive an individual record hash, _not_ an array of hashes. Do you think this warrants opening an issue on Github?

Comment: I really don't know enough about the strategy at play in the Ember internals to know if that's an issue or not.  It certainly wouldn't hurt to open an issue with a description of what you're trying to do, and your findings and see what the core team folks have to say about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37686/discussion-between-codefox421-and-jeremy-green)